# How can I simply add a downloadable PDF file to my page with vanila javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, web, portfolio

I want to create such a button on my portfolio website so that if someone clicks this button he/she can see my resume by pdf viewer and also download this pdf resume. how can I do it by vanilla javascript?

Comment: Why do you need JS for this? Links to download a file have been present since the first days of HTML, and they are still working great without a single line of JS

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to use javascript for this. Can't you just host the PDF file on the same website, and then put a link to the file? It should open it in the default PDF viewer in the browser, which often also allows viewers to download it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could convert your PDF content to base64 string.

And then you could do something like this.

```
  const content = 'data:application/pdf;base64,<base64 PDF content string>';
  const linkSource = content;
  const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
  const fileName = 'name.pdf';
  downloadLink.href = linkSource;
  downloadLink.download = fileName;
  downloadLink.click();
```